# Why I have a Segmentation fault in this small program?

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int, int> score;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    while(n--){
        int a,b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        score[a] = score[a] + b;
    }
    cout << score.rbegin()->first << " " << score.rbegin()->second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the error message is 16254 segmentation fault::11. Exit code: 139. And could you please why segmentation fault frequently happened when using map container.

Comment: What input are you using to run the program?

Comment: Evaluating `score[a]` twice is certainly inefficient, and I'm not 100% convinced that it's well-defined (although I'm fairly sure there's enough sequencing to get away with it). I'd write `score[a] += b;`

Comment: @MikeSeymour Doesn't standard guarantee that for an assignment the rhs is going to be evaluated first? Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but here is what I found: "The side effect (modification of the left argument) of the built-in assignment operator and of all built-in compound assignment operators is sequenced after the value computation (but not the side effects) of both left and right arguments, and is sequenced before the value computation of the assignment expression (that is, before returning the reference to the modified object)"

Comment: @triple_r: Yes, I think that's what it says, which is why I said I'm fairly sure there's enough sequencing. But I don't feel like unraveling the Standardese this early on a Monday, so I remain not 100% convinced. The simpler form is unambiguously well defined, as well as easier to read and more efficient.

Comment: @MikeSeymour :-) Fair enough. I was, and still am, a bit confused by the sequencing so wanted to know if I understood the standard correctly. Specifically, in this case, whether or not adding a new element to map is a side effect of evaluating the `operator[]` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` is `0`, you never populate `score`, and then you proceed to access an element from `score` without checking if it is empty.

In general, always prove an iterator is valid before using it.